# Can an r ggplot object be stored in an S4 slot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-s4

I am attempting to save a ggplot object in an S4 slot.

Consider:

```
library(stats4)
library(ggplot2)

setClass("gginS4",
      contains = c("ggplot"),
      slots = c(
        p = "ggplot"))
```

Allowing the ggplot to be accessed via `gginS4@p`.  I have used this approach for other classes of data (i.e., "sf", etc.) without issue. However, the above example yields the following error:

```
Error in reconcilePropertiesAndPrototype(name, slots, prototype, superClasses,  : 
  no definition was found for superclass “ggplot” in the specification of class “gginS4”
```

An object created with `ggplot2::ggplot()` has two classes `gg` and `ggplot`, but `setClass()` cannot find a definition for either of these superClasses. Is there another way to define the slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's dig a bit deeper to understand what is causing this

```
library(ggplot2)
isS3method("ggplot") # FALSE ,it means it is an S3 generic for more details: ?isS3method
```

You are trying to create a slot of `ggplot` generic which is implemented using S3 OO system so It will not work because of an incompatibility between the two systems.To store it inside the S4 slot, use `setOldClass`.

`setOldClass`: Register an old-style (a.k.a. ‘S3’) class as a formally defined class.

so final code should look like

```
library(ggplot2)
setOldClass(c("gg", "ggplot"))
setClass("gginS4",contains = "ggplot",
         slots = c(p = "ggplot"))
```

Comment: `ggplot` is a _generic_, so obviously not an S3 or S4 object. However, you are right in that you need to call `setOldClass` to use an S3 object inside an S4 object